# Lua: %UserProfile% access

Tags: filesystems, lua

I tried searching for this information, but no luck.

What I'm attempting to do is access a variable path in Lua, so instead of having to change a path to its absolute value each time, I can just do: `C:/%UserProfile%/path` instead. Is there a way to do this?

I saw a luafilesystem site, but it didn't seem to do what I needed it to do. Essentially, what I'd like to do is the following:

```
savepath = "%UserProfile%/Saves"
```

It won't matter if I have to have two steps or just one, just as long as it works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
os.getenv (varname)
```

Returns the value of the process environment variable varname, or nil if the variable is not defined.

--[Lua 5.1 Reference Manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-os.getenv)

Comment: Awesome! I KNEW it was something simple. Thanks!